# Using variable inside the def function globaly

Tags: python, function

**Here is my code**

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Hello, <b>{0.first_name}</b>!".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Enter your name".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, hello)

def hello(message):
    text = message.text
    print(text)
print(text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=123)
```

Here I use librarie telebot. So When I attempt to use variable text globaly I always fail.

I have an error: **NameError: name 'text' is not defined**

I have already attempted to use **global** parameter in a def but it wasn't succesfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `global` keyword and call the function `hello()` before print `text`:

```py
def hello(message):
    global text
    text = message.text
    print(text)
# call hello() in here
print(text)
```

Comment: I have the same error print(text)
NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: TypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Comment: because the function `hello()` require an agrument `message` so you have to pass a suitable value for it

Comment: Can you give an example pls

Comment: Somebody can help me?

Comment: can you suggest smthing pls

Comment: @elbekrustamov for more specific help, please add your full code and description of what you are trying to do